# How to pass enum value in angular template as an input?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular-template

I have a child component which takes type as an input
**child component :**

```
export enum PersonTypes {
  MALE = 'male',
  FEMALE = 'female'
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child'
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() type: PersonTypes;
}
```

**Parent component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent'
})
export class ParentComponent {

}
```

In the Parent component View template:

```
 <div>
     <app-child [type]="PersonTypes.MALE"></app-child>
     <app-child [type]="PersonTypes.FEMALE"></app-child>
 </div>
```

so , the question is how to pass the different enum values in the template ?
i found one answer saying we need create a new variable in parent component and then assign that value to "type" in the template like below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template:` <div>
     <app-child [type]="malePerson"></app-child>
     <app-child [type]="femalePerson"></app-child>
 </div>  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
        malePerson = PersonTypes.MALE;
        femalePerson = PersonTypes.FEMALE;
    }
```

for me it is over killed solution , what if we have 10 enum properties , we end up creating 10 local variables and assigning them in the template is too much.

any better solution for this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use Enum in the template you just have to directly assign the Enum to the component public property.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent'
})
export class ParentComponent {
public PersonTypesEnum = PersonTypes; // direct reference 
}
```

Now PersonTypesEnum can be used in a template

```
<div>
     <app-child [type]="PersonTypesEnum.MALE"></app-child>
     <app-child [type]="PersonTypesEnum.FEMALE"></app-child>
 </div>
```